# CoronaSDK: Lua for iPhone and Android. Now...can I...?

Tags: iphone, android, lua, coronasdk

Create a display object, set a fill color, draw a square, save the object reference, then later *retrieve that object color*?

Relevant code (from memory):

```
var disp = display.createRect(5,5)
disp.setFillColor(255,128,64)
...
otherObject.setFillColor(disp.getFillColor()) -- this is I want to do
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no method for retrieving an object's color in Corona SDK. However, you can save the color of an object in a variable (or table). See:

```
-- Table containing the RGB values of object 1 color:
local obj1Color = { r = 255, g = 0, b = 0 }

-- Draw a square at point (0,0) with side = 50px:
local obj1 = display.newRect(0, 0, 50, 50)
obj1:setFillColor(obj1Color.r, obj1Color.g, obj1color.b)

-- You can set and get the alpha value using dot notation:
print(obj1.alpha) -- will print 1
obj1.alpha = 0.5  -- set the opacity of obj1 to 50%
```

Comment: Getting/setting the alpha I'm aware of.  I was looking to get the _color_ of the square, but if not, oh well.